# php array change. How to get the keys of continuous values of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I want get the keys of continuous values of an array.
For example:

how to change this array:

```
array(
   2 => 11,
   3 => 11,
   4 => 11,
   6 => 12,
   7 => 13,
   8 => 13,
   10 => 11,
   11 => 11,
   12 => 14
)
```

to this one:

```
array(
    array(2, 3, 4),
    array(6),
    array(7, 8),
    array(10, 11),
    array(12)
)
```

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(
   2 => 11,
   3 => 11,
   4 => 11,
   6 => 12,
   7 => 13,
   8 => 13,
   10 => 11,
   11 => 11,
   12 => 14
);

$result = array();
array_walk(
    $data,
    function ($value, $key) use (&$result){
        static $v;
        if ($value == $v) {
            $result[max(array_keys($result))][] = $key;
        } else {
            $result[] = array($key);
        }
        $v = $value;
    }
);

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited Code.

```
<?php
$arr = [2 => 11, 3 => 11,4 => 11, 6 => 12, 7 => 13, 8 => 13, 10 => 11, 11 => 11,12 => 14];

$newArr = [];
$lastVal = null;
$currArr = [];
foreach($arr AS $key=>$value){
    if($lastVal == $value){
        $curArr[] = $key;
    }else{
        if($lastVal != null){
            $newArr[] = $curArr;
        }
        $lastVal = $value;
        $curArr = [$key];
    }
}
$newArr[] = $curArr;
```

I'm sure there's a more elegant way.

Comment: No, your code will change array to this:
`code`
array (
  11 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 3,
    2 => 4,
    3 => 10,
    4 => 11,
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    0 => 6,
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    0 => 7,
    1 => 8,
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    0 => 12,
  ),
)
`code`